# Can a slider control be programmatically added to an Excel VBA userform similar to frames, labels, etc?

Tags: excel, vba, slider, userform

I am trying to programmatically add Microsoft Slider controls to a userform.

The standard controls in the Microsoft 2.0 Object library work when calling them via the designer with a macro such as below:

```vb
Sub NewForm()
    
    Dim TempForm As Object
    Dim NewLabel As MSForms.Label
    Dim NewFrame As MSForms.Frame
    
    Set TempForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)
    With TempForm
        .Properties("Height") = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("F7").Value
        .Properties("Width") = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("F8").Value
        .Properties("Caption") = ""
    End With
    
    Set NewFrame = TempForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.frame.1")
    With NewFrame
        .Name = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("P6").Value
        .Caption = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("P10").Value
        .Height = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("P12").Value
        .Left = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("P13").Value
        .Top = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("P14").Value
        .Width = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("P15").Value
        .BorderStyle = 1
        .SpecialEffect = 0
    End With
    
End Sub
```

I have had no success adding slider controls which I believe come from a separate library, the 'Microsoft Slider Control v6'. It fails at every step to where I'm questioning if it is even possible.

This project will have >100 unique userforms. To reduce bloat I wish to draw the individual userforms each time on the fly instead of storing all of them.

Comment: This Control belongs to the MSCOMCTL.OCX And I guess you need a  reference to the Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0
But this is anyway dangerous if somebody has Excel 64 bit you will not be happy with these controls

Comment: The class name you want is `MSComctlLib.Slider.2`

Comment: Thanks @Rory, that worked with MSComctlLib.Slider.2. I had to comment out the Dim for it to work. How do I add the slider to NewFrame instead of TempForm?

Comment: Use: `NewFrame.Controls.Add("MSComctlLib.Slider.2")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following macro works to create a userform, frame and then add a Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 slider and a MSForms label to the frame. The slider is not declared as I couldn't find a Dim spec that worked. It seems to work fine without it. Note the omission of `.designer` when adding controls to the frame and not the userform. Thanks to Rory for his helpful comments.

```
    Sub NewForm()
    
    Dim TempForm As Object
    Dim NewLabel As MSForms.Label
    Dim NewFrame As MSForms.Frame
    'Dim NewSlider As MSComctlLib.Slider
    
    Set TempForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)
    With TempForm
    .Properties("Height") = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("F7").Value
    .Properties("Width") = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("F8").Value
    .Properties("Caption") = ""
    End With
    
    Set NewFrame = TempForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.frame.1")
    With NewFrame
    .Name = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("P6").Value
    .Caption = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("P10").Value
    .Height = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("P12").Value
    .Left = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("P13").Value
    .Top = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("P14").Value
    .Width = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("P15").Value
    .BorderStyle = 1
    .SpecialEffect = 0
    End With
    
    Set NewLabel = NewFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.label.1")
    With NewLabel
    .Name = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("V6").Value
    .BorderStyle = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("V8").Value
    .Caption = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("V9").Value
    .TextAlign = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("V10").Value
    .WordWrap = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("V11").Value
    .Font.Name = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("V12").Value
    .Font.Size = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("V13").Value
    .Height = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("V14").Value
    .Left = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("V15").Value
    .Top = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("V16").Value
    .Width = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("V17").Value
    End With
    
    Set NewSlider = NewFrame.Controls.Add("MSComctlLib.Slider.2")
    With NewSlider
    .Name = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI6").Value
    .Orientation = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI7").Value
    .TextPosition = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI8").Value
    .TickFrequency = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI9").Value
    .TickStyle = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI10").Value
    .LargeChange = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI11").Value
    .SelectRange = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI12").Value
    .SelLength = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI13").Value
    .SelStart = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI14").Value
    .SmallChange = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI15").Value
    .Max = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI16").Value
    .Min = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI17").Value
    .Height = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI18").Value
    .Left = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI19").Value
    .Top = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI20").Value
    .Width = Worksheets("PanelSpec").Range("AI21").Value
    End With

End Sub
```